# Access Instance Variables outside class - Ruby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have seen quite a few posts on this topic and apologise for not being able to use them for my example but i can seem to get it to work

I have a form that can be pre populated with the users information if the data exisits

```
def new
  BraintreeTransaction::PopulateForm.new(@user).populate_form
end

module BraintreeTransaction
  class PopulateForm
    def initialize(user)
      @user = user
    end

    def populate_form
     return if Transaction.where(user_id: @user.id, completed: false).empty?
     user_details = Transaction.where(user_id: @user.id, completed: false).order(created_at: :desc).first
     @first_name = user_details.first_name if user_details.first_name.present?
     @last_name = user_details.last_name if user_details.last_name.present?
   end
end
```

My Form

```
<%= text_field_tag :first_name, @first_name, placeholder: 'First Name', required: true %>
<%= text_field_tag :last_name, @last_name, placeholder: 'Last Name', required: true %>
```

How do i access the instance variable in this situation?

Thanks

Comment: You mean `@user`? You need and accessor, like `attr_reader :user` (or manually define `def user; @user end`)

Comment: could you explain why `@user` ?

Comment: Your title mentions accessing a "class instance variable", and `@user` is an instance variable, so I supposed you were asking how to access it outside of `PopulateForm`. If I made the wrong assumption let me know.

Comment: By the way, _instance variable_ and _class instance variable_ are different things. Simplifying things a bit, the latter is a variable of a Class instance (i.e., of some class), while the former is a variable of an Object instance.

Comment: There are no class instance variables in the code you posted. Could you please make sure to post the *actual* code corresponding to your question? Otherwise it is impossible to answer the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer here is to add `attr_reader` which makes these variables accessible:

```
class BraintreeTransaction::PopulateForm
  attr_reader :first_name
  attr_reader :last_name

  # ...
end
```

Then you can access these only if you capture the populate module:

```
def new
  @populate = BraintreeTransaction::PopulateForm.new(@user).populate_form
end
```

In your view you can then use them like this:

```
<%= text_field_tag :first_name, @populate.first_name, ... %>
```

I'd recommend doing this lazy-loading style though, to avoid having to manually initialize it:

```
class BraintreeTransaction::PopulateForm
  def initialize(user)
    @user = user
  end

  def first_name
    user_details and user_details.first_name
  end

  def last_name
    user_details and user_details.last_name
  end

  def user_details
    @user_details ||=
      Transaction.where(
        user_id: @user.id,
        completed: false
      ).order(
        created_at: :desc
      ).first
end
```

This has the effect of cutting your queries in half and caching the result so only the first access has cost. Calling `populate_form` manually is implicit, no longer required.

Comment: wow that's a great answer and really simple to follow, thank you

Comment: would you mind explaining the `user_details` method please, mainly the `@user_details ||=` thanks

Comment: also i've noticed you namespaced the class and not have module > class.. is this a better practice? do i not need to declare a module ?

Comment: I've just collapsed the `module X class Y` definition into `class X::Y` for brevity here. Generally if you have a `module X` definition in `x.rb` and `class Y` in `x/y.rb` then the autoloader will figure it out. I find the less nesting you do the better, so I tend to use the shorter method.

Comment: The Ruby idiom `@x ||= y` only initializes `@x` with a value if `@x` is a non-true boolean value, that is `nil` or `false`. It's often used as a "lazy initializer", or one that's generally called once and only once. This one is a little too lazy, you may end up running that query several times if there's no match, but you can make it less lazy with a bit more work. The example here does the job, though. `x ||= y` is equivalent to `x = x || y` or more specifically `x = y unless x`.

Comment: wow, are you available as a mentor, you're explanations are great :-) thanks again

Comment: I try and you're welcome! I've been considering making use of [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io/) more often for things like that.

Comment: Ive used that a few times now, find talking about a problem far more beneficial, you should sign up on there

Comment: I'm on there. Just haven't spent much time there yet.